# cudaGetDeviceCount giving 0 but i have tesla c2075 on hp z820 workstation

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I installed NVIDIA driver come with the Tesla c2075 card rather than driver present in cuda 5.0
The driver has version NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-**275.21**.run. Somewhere I read that driver installation gives problem in running CUDA programs is it due to that or something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That driver is too old for cuda 5.  cuda 5 requires driver 304.54 or newer.

Use the cuda driver (304.54) that comes in the cuda 5 package.  It will work fine on your tesla C2075.

Or if you want the latest driver, it is [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-319.23-driver.html).

Also, if you do [cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda?sort=frequent) on your cuda api calls (like `cudaGetDeviceCount`) you will get more information about what is going wrong.

Comment: Sir i am using centos 6.4 which has gcc with version 4.4.7 but CUDA 5 require gcc version 4.4.5 as per following link [CUDA rel note](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#linux)
Can I downgrade gcc to 4.4.5 or below

Comment: Actually I think 4.4.7 will be OK.  If you're having trouble using 4.4.7, please post a new question with the details of the problems you are having.  Although the link you reference mentions 4.4.5, that simply means what CUDA was *tested* with.  If you look in `/usr/local/cuda/include/host_defines.h` you will see that the enforced limit is 4.6.x or below.  If you really want to install a different gcc/g++, it is possible, you can search on those topics on stack overflow.